# How to redirect output?

Tags: powershell, io, windows-xp

I am attempting to redirect output of a Powershell script to a txt file.

In the Powershell window, I try:

> .\script.ps1 > list.txt

But it does not help, all output still gets printed to the window.

I then tried:

> .\script.ps1 >& list.txt

And got this error:

```
Missing file specification after redirection operator.
At line:1 char:21
+ .\script.ps1 > <<<< & list.txt
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingFileSpecification
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are writing output in script.ps1 using `Write-Host` (or `[Console]::WriteLine`) you will either need to change those to `Write-Output` or do this:

```
powershell.exe -File test.ps1 > out.txt
```

By the way `>` is syntactic sugar for `Out-File`, they are the same thing.

Comment: Now I'm getting : "Missing file specification after redirection operator." I tried a lot of variations I could think of :(

Answer (score 0):

If the output you're wanting to capture is being written to the console using Write-Host, you need to change that to Write-Output.

Comment: The script uses [Console]::WriteLine

Comment: @JBurace `[Console]::WriteLine` and `Write-Host` are basically the same thing. `[Console]::Write` is `Write-Host -NoNewLine`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `&` after the `>`. It is only used to execute something.

```
.\script.ps1 > list.txt
```

If `script.ps1` is outputting using `Write-Host` or `[Console]::WriteLine` you will need to update it.

[Here](http://www.powershellpro.com/write-host/171/) is an example of updating a `Write-Host` script to be outputable.

Comment: You probably mean `Write-Host`. `Write-Output` works fine with `> list.txt`.